# AWS SAM template - using sam local, how to fix environment variables with value '}'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have a sam template with environment variable with value }. This is causing an issue when running sam local due to parsing error.

`template.yaml`

```
Environment:
  Variables:
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: REDACTED
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: REDACTED
     DB_NAME: REDACTED_DB_NAME
     DB_USER: REDACTED_USER
     DB_PASS: }reDactedStringOfPW
     DB_DIALECT: mysql
     DB_HOST: REDACTED_HOST
     DB_PORT: REDACTED_PORT
```

Everything works fine if the password used is not prefixed with `}`. I could change the password as an easy fix but how do we proceed with this error - provided that I'm not allowed to change the value?

Below is the exact error when running sam local

```
$ sam local invoke --skip-pull-image --event ./devfiles/event.json --template ./devfiles/template.yaml
Error: Failed to parse template: while parsing a block node
expected the node content, but found '}'
  in "<unicode string>", line 42, column 20:
              DB_PASS: }reDactedStringOfPW
                       ^
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping it?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such kinds of syntax issues and ensure security best practice of your **Infra As Code** operations, you can create a [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to store your password credential.

With **CloudFormation** or **AWS SAM**, you can *dynamically resolve your password* with `{{resolve:ssm:<PARAMETER_NAME>:<PARAMETER_VERSION>}}` method.

```
Environment:
  Variables:
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: REDACTED
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: REDACTED
     DB_NAME: REDACTED_DB_NAME
     DB_USER: REDACTED_USER
     DB_PASS: {{resolve:ssm:MyDatabasePassword:1}}
     DB_DIALECT: mysql
     DB_HOST: REDACTED_HOST
     DB_PORT: REDACTED_PORT
```

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store-secure-string-parameters-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/